# Dart - The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: dart

My code is pretty simple:

```dart
typedef GenericCallback = void Function<T>(T);

void main() {
  GenericCallback callback = <String>(String message) => printMessage(message);
}

void printMessage([String errorMessageReason]) {
  print(errorMessageReason ?? '');
}
```

And DartPad gives me this error at the word `message` in `printMessage(message)`:

> Error: The argument type 'String/*1*/' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String/*2*/'.
>    - 'String/*1*/' is from 'unknown'.
>    - 'String/*2*/' is from 'dart:core'.

It looks like Dart is getting the reference from one `String` and not the other, how's this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've done `typedef GenericCallback = void Function<T>(T)` you need to provide a generic method which matches the signature as a callback. The tricky part here is, you *are* doing that but not in the way you think.

In this line it looks like you're trying to specify the type for the closure you've created:

```dart
GenericCallback callback = <String>(String message) => printMessage(message);
```

However, Dart's rules for naming generic type parameters are strange in that you can use the names of existing types *as the name of the type parameter*. In other words, the following lines are all functionally identical and will provide a similar error:

```dart
GenericCallback callback = <String>(String message) => printMessage(message);
GenericCallback callback = <T>(T message) => printMessage(message);
GenericCallback callback = <int>(int message) => printMessage(message);
```

These generic closures are all completely valid and even built-in types like `int` and `String` will be treated as the names for type parameters in the scope of the closure.

In order to fix your error, you'll want to change the type parameter `String` to have a different name that doesn't collide with a core type, and do one of the following:

- Update your invocation of `printMessage` to cast `message` to a `String`, although this will fail if `T` isn't of type `String` when the closure is called.

```dart
GenericCallback callback = <T>(T message) => printMessage(message as String);
```

- Update your typedef to expect a `String` parameter

```dart
typedef GenericCallback = void Function<T extends String>(T);

GenericCallback callback = <T extends String>(T message) => printMessage(message);
```

This is an easy mistake to make if you've come from a language which allows for template/generic specialization like C++. Keep in mind that, at least currently, you can't specialize a generic method or object and the generic type isn't assigned until the method is actually called or object is created.

Comment: hmm that's tricky, I come from a Java/C# background and I am loving Dart, but I guess generics need a bit more polishing. Thanks again Ben

Comment: I found this on Flutter `basic_types.dart`: `typedef ValueSetter<T> = void Function(T value);`, it works, but it's tricky as well, as if I do `(String message)` it shows an error, but `(message)` is just fine, I guess it's the specialization limitation right?

Comment: So, what's the idea to use generics then if you need to define a specific type for the callback?