# Dart - A value of type 'bool' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'

Tags: flutter, dart, generics

Pasting the following into [dartPad.dev](https://DartPad.dev) gives the error for the assignment `classtwoInstance.fieldOne = arg;`

*Error: A value of type 'bool' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'*

Casting to a bool also gives an '*unnecessary cast*' message

How do I assign the bool argument *arg* to fieldOne?

```
class ClassOne {
     Function<T>(T) setFunction;
  
     ClassOne({this.setFunction});
}

class ClassTwo {
    bool fieldOne;
}


testFunction<T>(T value){
    ClassTwo classtwoInstance = ClassTwo();
    ClassOne classOneInstance = ClassOne(setFunction: <bool>(bool arg) {
    classtwoInstance.fieldOne = arg; // Error A value of type 'bool' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'
       return null;
    });
  
   return classOneInstance;
}


void main() {

ClassOne classWithFunction = testFunction<bool>(true);
   classWithFunction.setFunction(true);
}
```

Comment: I hope this helps, it is similar to your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474675/dart-the-argument-type-string-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-strin

Comment: It is not a problem. It is incorrect code. Two different bool. One declared in dart:core, (as class) another bool declared in function (as generic type but not a dart::bool at all). So they are not compatible. Because second boll can be any type (eg: String, if String value will be passed as argument), because it is a generic (unspecified at the compile time). I cannot find the question? What you want to ask? Why dart:core:bool is not the same as type parameter bool? But it can be renamed to any name and effect would be the same. Eg. `setFunction: <MyCoolBool>(MyCoolBool arg)`

Comment: The same effect even it renamed. `A value of type 'MyCoolBool' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'.`

Comment: @Pablotortosalopez That link suggests to cast as the type which for me highlights a warning "unnecessary cast" and the second suggestion to extend "String type" wont work for bool.

However it has pointed me in the right direction. I've found that a ternary condition on previousCustomer assignment to check for null works! However I previously tested for a null in an if condition before assigning and that didnt work

Comment: @mezoni The question i want to ask is explicitly stated in my post as "How do I assign the bool argument arg to fieldOne?"
None the less I have found the answer and will post

Comment: @goodness Second type `bool` (generic parameter type) is not the same as `dart:core:bool` type.  How do you think that you can assign incompatible values? The simple answer: You cannot assign values of incompatible  types.

Comment: @mezoni ClassOne's constructor requires a function that satisfies the generic and in my example [ClassOne(setFunction: <bool>(bool arg) {...}] the generic T is set as a dart:core:bool hence why [classtwoInstance.fieldOne = arg ?? false] works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227796/discussion-between-goodness-and-mezoni).

Comment: @goodness which one?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a generic type on your `Function<T>(T) setFunction`, the compiler gets confused when it's set to as bool in `testFunction()`. What you can do here is change the data type to generic and then cast `arg` with bool when setting to `cassTwoInstance.fieldOne`

Here's the updated code that you can try on [dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true)

```dart
class ClassOne {
  Function<T>(T) setFunction;

  ClassOne({required this.setFunction});
}

class ClassTwo {
  bool? fieldOne;
}

testFunction<T>(T value) {
  ClassTwo cassTwoInstance = ClassTwo();
  ClassOne classOneInstance = ClassOne(setFunction: <T>(T arg) {
    cassTwoInstance.fieldOne = arg as bool; 
    print('ClassTwo fieldOne: ${cassTwoInstance.fieldOne}');
    return null;
  });

  return classOneInstance;
}

void main() {
  ClassOne classWithFunction = testFunction<bool>(false);
  classWithFunction.setFunction(false);
}
```